# CSS Animation: Fade in + transform animation for each word not working

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I'm trying to get each word to start at 0 opacity and translateY(65px). Then fade in one word at a time while transitioning to translateY(0). Each word is fading in, but does not translate.  Here's an example of what i'm trying to accomplish: https://www.bigdropinc.com/ (scroll down to paragraph)

```js
var $el = $(".example:first"), text = $el.text(),
    words = text.split(" ");

var html = "";
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    html += "<span>" + words[i] + " </span>";
};
$el.html(html).children().each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass('fadeInUp');
});
```

```css
@keyframes fadeInUp{
    0%{
    transform: translateY(65px);
    opacity: 0;
    }
    100%{
        opacity:1;
        transform:none;
    }
}
.fadeInUp{
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out,transform .8s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    animation:fadeInUp 3s forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">
    These are some words that should be faded in and transformed one after the other.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the display property for transform to work at all:

```js
var $el = $(".example:first"), text = $el.text(),
    words = text.split(" ");

var html = "";
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    html += "<span>" + words[i] + " </span>";
};
$el.html(html).children().each(function(i){
  $(this).addClass('fadeInUp');
});
```

```css
@keyframes fadeInUp{
    0%{
    transform: translateY(65px);
    opacity: 0;
    }
    100%{
        opacity:1;
        transform:none;
    }
}
.fadeInUp{
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out,transform .8s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    animation:fadeInUp 3s forwards;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">
    These are some words that should be faded in and transformed one after the other.
</div>
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But in your example each word in not transforming one at a time. I'm looking for this effect: https://www.bigdropinc.com/ (scroll down to first paragraph)

Comment: Yes, I saw this, but it was already like this in your code. I just solved the problem that you reported. Just change the code that adds the class to do so in a setinterval function and it will work